# T-SQL to find multiple orders from same customer on same day within given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to prepare a report for work where I need to see if a customer has cancelled and re-submitted an order.  Without any way to link the two orders all I have to go on is the customer_id, the order_date and the status.  I need to find all customers within a specific date range which have more than one order record for a customer placed on the same day, to return the customer_id would be enough

```
order_id    customer_id         order_date              status
1           1234                30/12/2013 09:10:55     CANCELLED
2           2222                30/12/2013 09:17:12     APPROVED
3           4321                30/12/2013 10:04:10     APPROVED
4           1234                30/12/2013 10:22:01     APPROVED
```

In the example data above it would find orders 1 and 4 and return the customer_id 1234.  It doesn't really matter what the status is as I can pick those out of the report anyway.

I've done a bit of digging and come up with something like this:

```
SELECT customer_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM orders AS o2
    WHERE (order_date = o1.order_date)) AS counter
FROM            orders AS o1
WHERE        (order_date BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01')
GROUP BY customer_id, order_date
HAVING        (counter >= 2)
```

but I get an error when trying to run that so I'm clearly getting something a bit wrong somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subquery is a bit off, but you could skip the subquery entirely and do it by simply grouping by `customer_id` and the date part of `order_date` and counting the results per day;

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_date >= '2013-12-01' AND order_date < '2014-01-02'
GROUP BY customer_id, CAST(order_date AS DATE)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bb3b/1).

Note that since you have an arbitrary time attached to your date, you can't easily use `BETWEEN` without converting to `DATE` in the where clause too. It's easier to just compare the dates directly (the upper bound with less than to cover all times on the previous day)

Comment: That seems to work just fine Joachim, I was obviously just making it more complicated that it needed to be.  Thanks for the help!